# Errror show "libffmpeg.so:text relocations" on vitamio?

Tags: android, android-studio, java-native-interface, native, vitamio

I have read [Text relocation and crash in android 6.0](https://github.com/vbartacek/aacdecoder-android/issues/76)  . But when I follow that's instruction error always show. Actually video had appear, but when I change to another application and back again to my app. The error  "**Detected problems with app native libraries (please consult log for detail):libffmpeg.so:text relocation**" always show.

**This is my code :- **

**Gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pripun.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation project(':vitamio')
}
```

**Android Manifest**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pripun.myapplication">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="io.vov.vitamio.activity.InitActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="portrait" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Class**

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

import io.vov.vitamio.Vitamio;
import io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
    public VideoView mVideoView;
    public Uri uri;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout);
        Vitamio.isInitialized(this);
        mVideoView=findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
        String url="rtsp://xxxxxx/Streaming/xxxx/xxx/xxxx";
        uri = Uri.parse(url);
        mVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
        mVideoView.setContentDescription(url);
        mVideoView.requestFocus();
        mVideoView.start();
        mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new io.vov.vitamio.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(io.vov.vitamio.MediaPlayer mp) {
                mVideoView.setBackgroundResource(0);
            }
        });
        mVideoView.setOnErrorListener(new io.vov.vitamio.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onError(io.vov.vitamio.MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView
        android:id="@+id/surface_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

How to handle or remove that error show ?